# Why wouldn't Zeus give Aphrodite to Ares when he was the obvious choice?

Tags: greek, aphrodite, ares

Why did Aphrodite have to marry Hephaistos, when Ares was the obvious choice?
As I understand it, the reason for the marriage to Hephaistos, was because Aphrodites' beauty caused conflict. Wouldn't it make more sense to give her to the powerful Ares? So that whoever would try to get his hands on her, would be crushed by Ares. They were lovers anyways, so why wasn't Ares chosen as her husband?

Comment: The interpretation I took was that Hephaestus, being crippled, was the only god who *wouldn't* crush anyone who put his hands on her. She was the goddess of love and was going to take lovers anyway; why give her a crazy jealous husband?

Answer (score 4):

Aphrodite was the goddess of love. She was described as exceedingly beautiful. And no matter what happens, she was going to get lovers. By giving her to Hephaestus, Zeus effectively ruled out a chance of a civil war breaking out between the gods. Obviously, Aphrodite wasn't going to be pleased by a cripple, and she would willingly have affairs with the other gods. And Hephaestus wasn't going to do anything about it. (Although he did, but that's another story)

Answer (score 0):

In some myths it's believed that it would be easier to marry Aphrodite off to a man who would be okay with him being cheated on - like Hephaestus.

But in other stories it's said that Hephaestus demand to marry Aphrodite in order to free his mother, Hera (I don't remember why she would need to be freed), because Zeus promised him anything he'd like. At first he asked for Athena's hand, but that lead to Hephaestus trying to rape her. But after he then asks for Aphrodite instead, because she is after all the goddess of beauty.